# List consistently deleted when program is run on Ti-89

Tags: ti-basic

Whenever I attempt to run a program on my Ti-89 that stores a number or a sequence into a list, the list is always deleted after the program is run. I have tried this sort of thing on a Ti-84, and the number is successfully stored. I was perhaps thinking that it may be due to a specific formatting error. An example program below:

```
mn()
Prgm
31->c
While c>0
If remain(sqrt(c^2*(c+1)),1)=0
Then
c->list2
EndIf
c-1->c
EndWhile
EndPrgm
```

Perhaps the number is not stored into the next blank cell and the entire list is cleared/deleted? I know on the Ti-84, one can simply use:
    c->L2(1+dim(L2))
Which does not seem to work on the Ti-89. Has anyone else had experience with this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding an element to `list2`, you're *replacing* `list2` with the contents of `c`.

First: `c->list2[1+dim(list2)]` does work, you just have to use square brackets for list indexing on an 89, not parentheses.

Second: you could keep a counter as you go: `1->i` at the beginning of the loop, and then
`c->list2[i] : i+1->i` for each value.

Third: `augment(list2,{c})->list2` also works, although it's probably the most expensive by far.